# About sequential code in FPGAs

Tags: vhdl, fpga

In VHDL, in a `process` all steps will be executed sequentially, but I wonder how an FPGA can execute steps sequentially. I am very confused about how sequential assignments, functions and similar are being generated in an FPGA, so can anyone throw some light on this topic?

```
process(d, clk)  
begin    
  if(rising_edge(clk)) then  
    q <= d;  
  else
    q <= q;  
  end if;    
end process;
```

This is just code for a simple D-Latch, but how will this be implemented in an FPGA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not "executed" sequentially as such - but the synthesizer interprets the code sequentially, and creates the hardware design to fit such an interpretation.

For instance, if you assign a value to a `signal` twice during a clocked process, the first assignment is simply ignored, while the second takes effect (remember that a `signal` is only assigned at the end of a `process` statement, not immediately):

```
signal a : UNSIGNED(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');

(...)

process(clk)
begin
  if(rising_edge(clk)) then
    a <= a - 1;
    a <= a + 1;
  end if;
end process;
```

The above process will always increment `a` by 1. Similarly, if you have the second assignment inside an `if` statement, the synthesizer will simply create two paths for `a` - a decrement for when the `if` statement is not fullfilled, and an increment for when it is.

If you use variables, the idea is the same - although intermediate values are used, as variables take on their new value immediately.

But it all boils down to that the synthesizer does all the "magic" of interpreting your `process` in a sequential way, then generating hardware that does what you have described.

Your example basically describes a d-flip-flop (the Xilinx FPGA tools iirc distinguish latches and flip-flops in that flip-flops are edge-sensitive, and latches are level-sensitive), although in a different way than typically recommended.

You can basically write the same code as:

```
process(clk)
begin
  if(rising_edge(clk)) then
    q <= d;
  end if;
end process;
```

It will automatically keep its value in the other cases. This will be implemented as a flip-flop inside the FPGA. Most FPGAs consist of blocks of look-up tables and flip-flops, to which quite a lot of different hardware can be mapped. The above code will simply by-pass the look-up table, and just use the flip-flop of one of the blocks.

You can learn more about the internal workings by having a look at the datasheet for your particular FPGA. For Spartan3-series FPGAs for instance, have a look at page 24 of the [Xilinx Spartan3 FPGA Family Data Sheet](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds099.pdf)

Comment: Thank you so much But i think that signals are just like wires connecting different outputs or inputs and variables are like memory elements.............is this concept of mine is true or not???????

Comment: Signals can be likened to wires, yes. But when you assign a value to a signal in a clocked process, the synthesizer infers a flip-flop between the input signal and the output signal. Most tools should have a feature where you can see a generated RTL diagram of your code - experiment a bit with that, and have a look at how your code actually looks after being synthesized.